# export data from mongo to hive

Tags: mongodb, hadoop, hive

- my input: a collection("demo1") in mongo db (version 3.4.4 )
- my output : my data imported in a database in hive("demo2") (version  1.2.1.2.3.4.7-4)
- purpose : create a connector between mongo and hive

Error:

> Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. com/mongodb/util/JSON

---

I tried 2 solutions following those steps (but the error remains):

1) I create a local collection in mongo (via robomongo) connected to docker

2) I upload those version of jars and add it in hive

```
 ADD JAR /home/.../mongo-hadoop-hive-2.0.2.jar;
 ADD JAR /home/.../mongo-hadoop-core-2.0.2.jar; 
 ADD JAR /home/.../mongo-java-driver-3.4.2.jar;
```

Unfortunately the error doesn't change; so I upload those version, I hesitate in choosing right version for my export, so I try this:

```
ADD JAR /home/.../mongo-hadoop-hive-1.3.0.jar;
ADD JAR /home/.../mongo-hadoop-core-1.3.0.jar; 
ADD JAR /home/.../mongo-java-driver-2.13.2.jar;
```

3) I create an external table

```
    CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE demo2
    ( 
      id INT,
      name STRING,
      password STRING,
    email STRING 
    )
    STORED BY 'com.mongodb.hadoop.hive.MongoStorageHandler'
    WITH 

SERDEPROPERTIES('mongo.columns.mapping'='{"id":"_id","name":"name","password":"password","email":"email"}')
    TBLPROPERTIES('mongo.uri'='mongodb://localhost:27017/local.demo1');
```

- Error returned in hive :

> Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. com/mongodb/util/JSON

How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: Hi @Liz18 Were you able to find the solution to this? Really stuck with exactly this problem. Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Copying the correct jar files (`mongo-hadoop-core-2.0.2.jar`, `mongo-hadoop-hive-2.0.2.jar`, `mongo-java-driver-3.2.2.jar`) on **ALL** the nodes of the cluster did the trick for me.

Other points to take care about:

- Follow all steps mentioned here religiously - https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-hadoop/wiki/Hive-Usage#installation
- Adhere to the requirements given here - https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-hadoop#requirements

Other useful links

- https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-hadoop/wiki/FAQ#i-get-a-classnotfoundexceptionnoclassdeffounderror-when-using-the-connector-what-do-i-do
- https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mongodb-user/xMVoTSePgg0

Comment: To download all the JAR files mentioned - https://gist.github.com/akki/2bf5ef1abcf209148f33977c67034bae